# socket_read unblock in incomming multiple client with socket_accept

Tags: php, sockets

I have server socket that client can connect to me, Read and Write in socket like this

```
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_bind($socket, $address, $port))
socket_listen($socket);
socket_set_nonblock($socket);
```

I set socket_set_nonblock to nonblock my socket in socket_accept
this work good but for client that connect to my server I con't nonblock clients

```
while(true){
    if (($newc = @socket_accept($socket)) !== false) {
        //socket_set_nonblock($newc);
        //socket_set_option($socket,SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, array("sec"=>5, "usec"=>0));
        $clients[] = $newc;
        $data = socket_read($newc, 1024, PHP_NORMAL_READ);
    }
    echo "do sometings ...";
}
```

I test socket_set_nonblock($newc) and option SO_RCVTIMEO for prevent of blocking $newc in socket_read but I was not successful to nonblock

I test socket_select like below but this not work

```
 $write = array();
 $expect = NULL;
 socket_select($clients, $write, $except, 0);
```

when second client connect to program ***echo "do something..."*** don't work until second client input anything
for nonblocking socket_read what I must to do? It's impossible or I use socket_select incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

I invested hours to finally got something working. The socket_set_nonblock($newsock); for each income client is necessary for Linux (CentOS) PHP7, but it should work on windows PHP5.

```
<?php
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
// Set time limit to indefinite execution
set_time_limit(0);
// Set the ip and port we will listen on
$address = '127.0.0.1';
$port = 6901;
ob_implicit_flush();
// Create a TCP Stream socket
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
// Bind the socket to an address/port
socket_bind($sock, $address, $port) or die('Could not bind to address');
// Start listening for connections
socket_listen($sock);
// Non block socket type
socket_set_nonblock($sock);
// Clients
$clients = [];
// Loop continuously
while (true) {
    // Accept new connections
    if ($newsock = socket_accept($sock)) {
        if (is_resource($newsock)) {
            // Write something back to the user
            socket_write($newsock, ">", 1).chr(0);
            // Non bloco for the new connection
            socket_set_nonblock($newsock);
            // Do something on the server side
            echo "New client connected\n";
            // Append the new connection to the clients array
            $clients[] = $newsock;
        }
    }
    // Polling for new messages
    if (count($clients)) {
        foreach ($clients AS $k => $v) {
            // Check for new messages
            $string = '';
            if ($char = socket_read($v, 1024)) {
                $string .= $char;
            }
            // New string for a connection
            if ($string) {
                echo "$k:$string\n";
            } else {
                if ($seconds > 60) {
                    // Ping every 5 seconds for live connections
                    if (false === socket_write($v, 'PING')) {
                        // Close non-responsive connection
                        session_close($clients[$k]);
                        // Remove from active connections array
                        unset($clients[$k]);
                    }
                    // Reset counter
                    $seconds = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    sleep(1);
    $seconds++;
}
// Close the master sockets
socket_close($sock);
```